# What does the Psalm 75 title 'Al-Taschith' mean?

Tags: psalms, david

Robert Young's Analytical Concordance simply states :

> destroy or corrupt not

There is a Hebrew word *tashbets* meaning 'broidered' but that may not be relevant.

I am interested primarily in Psalm 75 in regard to the title adding to the meaning of the body of Asaph's psalm, but it also has a bearing on David's three psalms as well.

Can anyone shed some more light on this title of Psalms 57, 58, 59 and 75 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question with no non-speculative answers. The answers that have been proposed are:

1. *Al Tashhet* refers to the tune or rhythm of a song that was once well known, to which this Psalm should be set, possibly the tune used for Deuteronomy 9:26<sup>1</sup>
2. Various attempts to link these Psalms with themes of *tashet* (to waste, spoil or destroy) in the OT. For example I Sam 24:5 and 26:9<sup>2</sup>

---

1. "I prayed to the LORD and said, "Sovereign LORD, do not destroy your people, your own inheritance that you redeemed by your great power and brought out of Egypt with a mighty hand." (NIV)
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Herz_Tur-Sinai

Comment: Thank you. Informative. Up-voted +1.